# Vanilla JS - Trying to Shim Fake Data in place of JSON Response?

Tags: javascript, json, shim

I am trying to push fake data to test some code I have written that interacts with a third party, the reason it needs to be injected in this way is because the code doesn't exist in my test environment, so while I am receiving the correct data from the third party server, my test environment doesn't know what to do with it. So far I have created this;

```
const {fetch: origFetch} = window;

window.fetch = async (...args) => {
    console.log("fetch called with args:", args);
    const response = await origFetch(...args);

    response
        .clone()
        .json()
        .then(body => console.log("intercepted response:", body))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));

     /* the original response can be resolved unmodified: */
     //return response;

    /* or mock the response: */
    return {
        ok: true,
        status: 200,
        json: async () => ({
            'element': [
                'baseURI', 'https://#',
                'className', 'third-party-code',
                'dataSet', [
                    'displayMode', 'CAROUSEL',
                    'hideInMobile', 'true',
                    'navigationMethod', 'thirdParty',
                ],
            ],
            'productIds': [
                '1234567', 'https://#',
                'ABCDEFG', 'https://#',
                '8901112', 'https://#',
                'HIJKLMN', 'https://#',
            ],
        })
    };
};
```

Now while this kind of does what I want, it's not working as expected.

Firstly, it's intercepting the first AJAX JSON response it comes across, not the one I want, secondly, I'm still not sure it's going to work.

I really need someone to show me how I can create a SHIM that will a) use the JSON response if it is valid, and b) use the fake data when not on a production level environment, or the JSON response isn't valid.

Mainly I need help creating the SHIM so I can at least test this properly, but I'd also like to target a specific JSON response.

As always any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, the data is actually fetched by third party code?

Comment: I wasn't very clear about that sorry... The data is fetched from a 3rd party server, this data consists of the data you can see in the fake response (return ... json.async). I need to SHIM this in because the test server doesn't always have the information that the response should trigger. I'm sorry it's vague, but the system involved are pretty sensitive, so I am doing my best...